# A problem on a type of {m,n} tree

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

So here is the tree. For given $\left \{ m,n \right \}$. {m,n} will transform to give these elements which I will represent using a summation operator;

$$\sum^{n}_{k=1}\left \{ m-k,k \right \}$$

Take {9,3}. So In our example it becomes, $\left \{ 8,1 \right \},\left \{ 7,2 \right \},\left \{ 6,3 \right \}$. And with this we can continue on to look like this;

[image]

The Rules here are that, when either the $m$ or the $n$ values becomes $0$ or $1$, end the transformation. For example here, it ends at {8,1},{6,1},{4,1},..{0,2} etc. and there are $12$ of them.

The problem here is that, given $m,n$ where $n≤m$. Find the number of times the transformation "tree" stops.

Comment: I upvoted from -1 back to 0 because I thought that the OP did a nice job of describing a rather complicated problem, with a good diagram.  Further, while it is standard to punish an OP that does not **show his work,** I don't like applying that standard to problems where the OP might reasonably not see any plan of attack.

Comment: I could explain my work, if I did. But the only thing I can notice here is that all the resulting elements of a {m,n} is a composition of m with two addends. Example, {9,3} --> {8,1},{7,2},{6,3}. $8+1=7+2=6+3=9$. Maybe that is one way to view the problem.

Comment: That doesn't help much, it seems to me, because you can get the same leaf more than once.  In the diagram, both $\{2,1\}$ and $\{1,2\}$ appear multiple times.

Comment: @saulspatz, yes I think some kind of repetition happens, which also makes this problem much harder. You can notice that m appears to be 3 twice, but the $n$ value corresponding to it is different. It is rather easy to prove that {m,n} will only happen once but {m,n-1} etc, can happen.

Comment: I think you should try to work it out for fixed values of $n$.  We know $S(m,0)=S(m,1)=1$ and $S(m,2)=S(m-1,1)+S(m-2,2)=1+S(m-2,2)$ so we have a recurrence relation for $S(m,2).$  The recurrence relation for $S(m,3)$ will be third-order, but maybe you can solve it.  Hopefully, you can make a guess at the general pattern (if there is one) before $n$ gets too big.

Comment: We see easily that $$S(m,2)=1+\left\lfloor{m\over2}\right\rfloor$$

Comment: Yeah, I see that too. Now finding relations for more numbers would be hard. This can also be the reason that this is closely related to the partition function.

Comment: There are some patterns that do appear when we map these in a graph.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99926/discussion-between-fishfag-and-saulspatz).

Comment: I must have gone to the chatroom too late.  Sorry.  Anyway, look at the edit to my "answer".

Comment: Yeah saw that, I've also found something really interesting $S(m,m)=P(m)$, where $P(m)$ is the partition function.

Comment: Do you have a proof of that that you can post?

Comment: I don't have at the moment tho

Answer (score 1):

Just a comment, but it won't fit in a comment box.  I calculated the values for $S(m,3),\ 0\leq m<100$.  Note that I did get $S(9,3)=12$ as shown in the diagram.

**EDIT**

I've noticed that we always have $S(m,3)=m+S(m-6),\ m\geq6$ so there will definitely be recurrence relations though there may be $6$ different ones.

```
0 1
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 7
7 8
8 10
9 12
10 14
11 16
12 19
13 21
14 24
15 27
16 30
17 33
18 37
19 40
20 44
21 48
22 52
23 56
24 61
25 65
26 70
27 75
28 80
29 85
30 91
31 96
32 102
33 108
34 114
35 120
36 127
37 133
38 140
39 147
40 154
41 161
42 169
43 176
44 184
45 192
46 200
47 208
48 217
49 225
50 234
51 243
52 252
53 261
54 271
55 280
56 290
57 300
58 310
59 320
60 331
61 341
62 352
63 363
64 374
65 385
66 397
67 408
68 420
69 432
70 444
71 456
72 469
73 481
74 494
75 507
76 520
77 533
78 547
79 560
80 574
81 588
82 602
83 616
84 631
85 645
86 660
87 675
88 690
89 705
90 721
91 736
92 752
93 768
94 784
95 800
96 817
97 833
98 850
99 867
```

Comment: Is a similar identity valid for $S(m,4)$ too?

Comment: I haven't gotten that far yet.  I need to leave now, so it will be some time before I can get back to this.

Comment: I been thankful for the data you gave me, all this time, I been working on by hand. Laters.

Comment: I think the identity is, $$S(m,4)=m+S(m-6,3)+(m-4,4)$$